# Preventing a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following jQuery:

```js
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
    $(function () {     
        'use strict';
        Rh_Post_function();         
        // Rendered
        jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {   
            Rh_Post_function();
        });
    });
})(jQuery, this);
```

Here, I have two `Rh_Post_function ()`. One is inside `jQUery.ias()` (infinite ajax scroll) which calls the function again when more contents are loaded via ajax (which otherwise, the newly loaded content does not pass the `Rh_Post_function`).

However, now it is running twice.
Can I prevent so that if `jQuery.ias().on` is called, then the first function no longer works? (Meaning, only one function works instead of repeating twice).

Comment: Why do you have the first `Rh_Post_function` there?

Comment: You should use `one`

Comment: Well, there are situations in which the infinite scroll never kicks in (such as when there aren't enough contents to call more contents).

Comment: Maybe I can use if statements

Comment: You can call the infinite scroll on load and remove the first function.